# Laravel sum up values from multidimensional array collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have a collection like

```
$collection = collect([
   [
      ["studentId" => 3, "marks" => 10],
      ["studentId" => 7, "marks" => 15]
   ],
   [
      ["studentId" => 3, "marks" => 20],
      ["studentId" => 7, "marks" => 15]
   ],
   [
      ["studentId" => 3, "marks" => 10],
      ["studentId" => 7, "marks" => 20]
   ],
]);
```

I want to sum up `marks` for specific `studentId` and map the results like

```
[
   ["studentId" => 3, "marks" => 40],
   ["studentId" => 7, "marks" => 50],
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but you can probably do something like...

```php
$collection = collect([
   [
      ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 10],
      ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 15]
   ],
   [
      ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 20],
      ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 15]
   ],
   [
      ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 10],
      ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 20]
   ],
]);

$collection = $collection
    ->flatten(1)
    ->groupBy('studentId')
    ->transform(function($subItems, $studentId) {
        return [
            'studentId' => $studentId,
            'marks' => $subItems->sum('marks')
        ];
    })
    ->values();
```

What this does is...

**1. Flatten the array**

First we flatten the collection by 1 depth using the [`flatten`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatten) method. Resulting structure...

```
[
  ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 10],
  ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 15],
  ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 20],
  ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 15],
  ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 10],
  ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 20]
]
```

**2. Group values by**

Next we group all the values by the studentId using the [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby) method. Result...

```
[
  3 => [
    ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 10],
    ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 20],
    ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 10]
  ],
  7 => [
    ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 15],
    ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 15],
    ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 20]
  ]
]
```

**3. Sum the marks**

Now we calculate the groups of marks with the [`transform`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-transform) method. Result...

```
[
  3 => ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 40],
  7 => ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 50]
]
```

**4. Reset keys (optional)**

You'll notice in the last result that the top level array keys are the same as the studentId values this is left over from the groupBy method. We can reset these with the [`values`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-values) method. Result...

```
[
  ['studentId' => 3, 'marks' => 40],
  ['studentId' => 7, 'marks' => 50]
]
```